# Ratchet remove/add data-ignore="push"

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, ratchet, push.js

Using ratchet framework, I am able to slidein/slideout of any pages, I arrive on a situation where I have to get the data first before it slides to the next page. I can get the data but the slide transition of the page is gone. Is there a way to do this?

I have this example anchor here:

`<a href="next-link.html" data-transition="slide-in" data-want="I want this data here">Next link</a>`

tried using,

`$('a').each(function() {`

```
`var $this = $(this);`

`$this.attr('data-ignore', 'push');`

`$this.click(function(e) {`

    `e.stopPropagation();`

    `//... get the data here $this.attr('data-want')`

    `$this.attr('data-ignore', '');`

`});`
```

`});`

Answer (score 0):

use `.data()` instead:

```
$this.data('ignore', 'push');
```

and to set it empty

```
$this.data('ignore', '');
```

Comment: Nope, it still the same. .attr('data-value') and .data('value') is just the same right?

Comment: yes I have. It is basically the same. but ooopsss, I have found the answer.

e.stopPropagation() should not be there.

It's suppressing/bubbling of push.js. Silly me! :) Thank you btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use, the advantage of "on" is that it will work whenever an a tag is appended to the page.
You can remove the if statement if you want to, I'm using PhoneGap so this gets around some issues for me.

```
        $(document.body).on('click', 'a', function(e){
            $(this).attr('data-ignore', 'push');    //disables ratchet push.js for now!
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url && url.indexOf('http') == -1) {
                location.href = url;
            }
        });
```